# How to put a string with a php tag into a php variable?

Tags: php

I want to include

```
action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
```

in $render_form variable. But the following code does not work:

```
<?php $render_form = '<form method="post" action="<?php echo 
  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">
  <br> 
  </form>'; 
?>
```

The following code (without php tag) works:

```
<?php $render_form = '<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">
  <br>
  </form>'; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you, this should fit your issue

```
<?php $render_form = '<form method="post" action="'. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] .'">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">
  <br> 
  </form>'; 
?>
```

Comment: Hi BanNsS1, thanks for the reply- your code works. Would it be possible to provide explanation for this syntax: '. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] .' ?

Comment: Yeah, it's the way to concatenate strings in PHP:  $string = "My name is ". $name .", nice to meet you ". $stranger_name;

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php